# Activate button once email textbox and confirm textbox matches

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having difficult in VUEJS. I have this scenario that there are two email text boxes and once both the email textboxes matches, i want to activate my submit button.
Here is the code for the textboxes and button.

```
<div class="mb-2">
        <b-form-input
          :rules="{email: true, max: 255, required: true}"
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          v-model="innerValue.email"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-2">
        <b-form-input
          :rules="{email: true, max: 255, required: true}"
          label="Confirm email"
          name="confirm_email"
          type="email"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-2">
        <div class="action-button">
          <b-button @click="onSubmit" class="text-uppercase" variant="primary">Reset Password</b-button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How can i achieve the scenario, when the two textboxes matches, the submit button will be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Save your second email in a variable to check its value in button
- Add Conditions on button, If value not matches disable the click

---

```html
  <div class="mb-2">
    <b-form-input
      :rules="{email: true, max: 255, required: true}"
      label="Email"
      name="email"
      type="email"
      v-model="innerValue.email"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2">
    <b-form-input
      :rules="{email: true, max: 255, required: true}"
      label="Confirm email"
      name="confirm_email"
      type="email"
      v-model="innerValue.email2"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2">
    <div class="action-button">
      <b-button @click="onSubmit" :disabled="innerValue.email2 != 
       innerValue.email" 
       class="text-uppercase" 
       variant="primary">Reset Password</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without saving the second email into the database and check it from javascript side? @Phil

Comment: @Pheonix this isn't my answer, I just corrected the formatting. You want to address Aliasgher

Comment: @Aliasgher Nooruddin is it possible to do it without saving the second email into the database and check it from javascript side?

Comment: @phil my appology

Comment: I am not saving into database, I am just creating another variable and saving it there